# converting legacy as1/2 code into as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

i have a .swf which i have downloaded on the internet it is a animation that i would very much like to have it in my .swf however, when i am loading it and trying to control the .swf i get a error code.
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::AVM1Movie@10d52701 to flash.display.MovieClip.

i searched the net for this error and it is because the .swf is compiled in as1/2 therefore i am unable to get it's "object" and control it.

i have also decompiled the .swf and read the codes, but the codes are mostly done in as1/2 and i have no clue what it does, as i just started learning as3 , and have never touched as1/2.

anyone have any idea what can i do?the below is the code decompiled, from what i understand it is used to "shift" the parts of the animation. which is a "fish" body part, to create a very smooth, swimming action. i have tried converting it to as3 code but i get errors where it cant find the variables.

```
function corps(objet)
{
    i = 0;
    for (;;) 
    {
        if (i >= 8) 
        {
            return;
        }
        tourne = Math.cos(i + getTimer() / (400 - m)) * 9;
        objet["p" + i]._rotation = (0 - tourne) / 2;
        objet.p5["p" + i]._rotation = 0 - tourne;
        objet.p5.p4["p" + i]._rotation = 0 - tourne;
        objet.p5.p4.p3["p" + i]._rotation = 0 - tourne;
        objet.p5.p4.p3.p2["p" + i]._rotation = 0 - tourne;
        objet.p5.p4.p3.p2.p1["p" + i]._rotation = (0 - tourne) / 2;
        ++i;
    }
}
function fish(objeti)
{
    if (objeti._x && objeti._y) 
    {
        corps(objeti);
    }
}
var j = Math.random(20) * 7 - 5;
var m = Math.random(50) * 2;
j = 4;
m = 4;
k = 0;
u = 0;
v = 1;
this.poisson.s = 1;
this.poisson.vari = this.poisson._width / 10 + this.poisson._height / 10;
this.onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    fish(this.poisson);
}
;
```

Comment: decompiled code... you can always contact the original (francophone) programmer :-)

Comment: yea i did, but i think his english is not really good, i have trouble understanding what he typed to me.

Comment: Where you able to understand if he was OK with you decompiling and reusing it or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all the properties that begin with an `_` to it's corresponding AS3 property. I.e. `_width` should be `width`and `_rotation` should be `rotation`, do this for `_width, _height, _x, _y, _rotation`.

Comment: hi, i did that, but for the var letters i have no idea how it came there, this code is on the main timeline of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an instance of `poisson` to be placed on the Stage and named. Is it in the library? Be sure to name the instance `poisson`.